# Is it correct to say "I leave here"?

Tags: sentence-usage

Some people I know say that routinely: "I leave here", "I'm leaving here", "I'm going to leave here" and so on. Somehow that phrase doesn't feel right to me (I would've said either "I leave this place" or "I am out of here"); they insist it is correct, but, since neither of us is a native speaker of English, I don't trust them, but I don't trust my "gut feeling" either. Googling those exact phrases returned no results, but that may as well mean that they are not wrong but just too generic. Also, "I come here" is correct, and "come" is the same kind of word as "leave", so, perhaps, using "leave" instead of "come" isn't wrong either.

Is it grammatically correct, and if so, does it sound natural to say "I leave/am leaving here"?

Comment: If you are leaving a place, you simply say "I am leaving". You would not say "I am leaving here." "I am leaving" refers to "the place where the speaker currently is."

Comment: Try [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+leaving+here&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is grammatically correct and many English speakers would understand it. Other constructions are preferable in many regions.

Comment: _Here_ means _this place_, so there is absolutely nothing wrong with the phrase (though adding _here_ may not be strictly necessary).